# How to handle null when use SELECT new from JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I using Jpa and Spring but i have problem when i get data from db.

Entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id
   private String id

   private String noteId

   private String email

  //get and set
}

@Entity
public class Note{
   @Id
   private String id

   private String value

   private String description

  //get and set
}
```

I using JPA recive all information from database with two table note and employyee.
I write query look like

Repository

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.example.response.ResponseDto(e.id,e.email,n.description,n.value) FROM Employee e JOIN NOTE n ON e.noteId = n.id WHERE e.id = :id and  n.value = :value")
ResponseDto findAllEmployeeAndNote(String id, String value)
```

When i put id and value correct value in database. I get success response. But when i put **id** and **value** not found in database. JPA throw exception : `Result must not empty`

I want custom message `Result must not empty` and throw my custom exception. How to handle it

Comment: Catch the JPA exception and throw your custom one (ideally set the JPA exception as the cause)?

Comment: @Thomas
you mean 

When i call findAllEmployeeAndNote , i using try catch it ?

Comment: Could you please add code where you have used `findAllEmployeeAndNote`?.

Comment: You can return `Optional<ResponseDto>`

Comment: Thank you. Optional or try catch also work. Thanks so much